# How do I get a full input stream for my program?

Tags: c, loops, input

I've got a task that I need to input all the information of students (ID, name, grade) as the database as the source code below. My source code here is totally valid about the syntax (no error informed as my gcc does) but I can't input the grades of students. When I run my program, it skipped over the step of input the grade of student and step to input the next student ID. I've put `getchar()` to hold the `\n` character but it maybe not work at all or there is another reason for this error.

```
typedef struct 
{
    char id[10];
    char name[50];
    float grade;
    char assess;
}student;
student std[50];
    do {
        printf("How many students you want to add?\n");
        scanf("%d", &num);
        if(num<0 || num>50)
            printf("Your number must be positive or smaller than or equal to 50!\n");
    } while(num<0||num>50);

    for(i = a; i < num; i++)
    {
        printf("Student's id No.%d:", i);
        fgets(std[i].id, MAX, stdin);
        getchar();
        printf("Student's name No.%d:", i);
        fgets(std[i].name, MAX, stdin);
        getchar();
        printf("Student's grade No.%d:", i);
        do {
            scanf("%f", std[i].grade);
            if(std[i].grade < 0 || std[i].grade > 10)
                printf("Please re-input grade, it must be between 0 and 10\n");
        } while(std[i].grade < 0 || std[i].grade > 10);
        std[i].assess=assess(std[i].grade);
    }
```

Comment: `fgets` also read the end of line char, and put it in your string.

Comment: It would be good to know how exactly `std` is defined.

Comment: Also the already incomplete code shown, itself looks incomplete: The 2nd `while` looks orphaned. A clean&clear indention would help.

Comment: @alk Because thiis is just a small part of my program and my full version is very long and I think it's not necessary so I don't put all of them here

Comment: There is a `do` missing inside the `for`-loop you show. Even as a fragment it does not make sense.

Comment: @alk This is my faulr that i accidentally erase it out of my source code. It's actually do not affect the error I've got

Comment: To debug issues related to the `f/scanf*()`-family of functions it helps to inspect the value the functions return.

Comment: @alk I still don't get the way you want to say to debug the error I'm getting involved in. Can you show it more clearly?

Comment: The function `scanf()` returns the number of values scanned or `EOF` on error. Test this.

Comment: Also, what is `MAX`?

Comment: And again: It would be good to know how exactly `std` is defined!

Comment: @alk ok I will clarify your queries:
1 MAX is one that I've define before and MAX=100.
2. std is a variable that is define as a struct. For more detail: 
``
typedef struct 
{
    char id[10];
    char name[50];
    float grade;
    char assess;
}student;
``
and ``student std[50]``

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205449/discussion-between-hoang-nam-and-alk).

Comment: Drop the calls to `getchar()` after `fgets()` and add calls to `getchar()` after the `scanf()` calls. `fgets()` reads the new-line, the call to `scanf()`, as currently used do not.

Comment: Be aware that the new-line read by `fgets()` is read into it's argument.

Comment: Also pass to `fgets()` the size of the buffer you pass, 10 or 50 here. Using 100 does not make sense at all.

Answer (score 1):

To write data to memory location allocated for variables, you need to specify the address of the variable, you're using `scanf` on. So `scanf("%f", std[i].grade);` should be modified to `scanf("%f", &(std[i].grade) );`.

Due to aforementioned reason, your code has undefined behavior, which often but not always, results in Segmentation fault.

Comment: Oh I got it. But I don't know why my gcc do not show anything warning or error for this case

Comment: @HoangNam: Make it a habit passing `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` at least when invoking GCC to compile and take the warnings issued serious.

Comment: I've checked and altered my source code according to your answer but I still get that error. I think there must be something else wrong